# file_get_contents not working in a controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to receive file from android app created with nativescript using `nativescript-background-http` and the content-type is set as application/octet-stream.

therefore I am using file_get_contents to receive file in PHP.

this code works fine outside the laravel controller.

```
file_put_contents('uploads/' . $_SERVER['HTTP_FILENAME'], file_get_contents('php://input'));
```

I had added this to the .htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:File-Name} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_FILENAME:%{HTTP:File-Name}]
```

but once I move the code into my controller it doesn't work

```
public function createDocument(Request $request){
        file_put_contents('assets/atlantis/uploads/documents/' . $_SERVER['HTTP_FILENAME'], file_get_contents('php://input'));
    }
```

Please any suggestions why it wouldn't work inside laravel controller?
What can I do to fix this.

Thanks

Comment: Where is the uploads folder located in relation to the app folder? If `uploads` is in `public`, then use `public_path().'uploads...`. Using straight `uploads` as the beginning will have it start from the path you're in currently

Comment: I have the uploads folder outside located on the same level as the app folder. I modified and i moved the index.php and .htaccess from the public into the root folder and i modified the index.php to point to proper folders. Everythings works fine. I just can't get the file uploads to work

Comment: Try `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'../uploads/...'` to see if that works

Comment: What do you mean by "it doe'snt work" ? Have you some logs/stack trace/error message ? Also are you sure your permissions on specified directory are okay ?

Comment: Yes the permission my folders are ok 777 and when I say it doesn't work, I can't see the file uploaded and on the app it shows error. But when I move the code outside the controller it works and the file is uploaded. I checked an no error is reported